# react native with hermes source map not generated

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using window 11 and trying to generate react native typescript sourcemap when doing debugging with command `yarn create-env --staging && react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug --appIdSuffix=staging`

I expect to generate typescript sourcemap at `android/app/build/sourcemap`, but that folder doesn't exist. I have following docs at [https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/sourcemaps#:~:text=Source%20maps%20are%20disabled%20by,React%20Native%20code%20and%20images%22.&text=sh-,If%20done%20correctly%20%2D%20you%20may%20see%20the%20output%20location%20of,map%20during%20Metro%20build%20output](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/sourcemaps#:%7E:text=Source%20maps%20are%20disabled%20by,React%20Native%20code%20and%20images%22.&text=sh-,If%20done%20correctly%20%2D%20you%20may%20see%20the%20output%20location%20of,map%20during%20Metro%20build%20output).

update build.gradle at `android/app/build.gradle` with value like this

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    bundleInStaging: true,  
    bundleInRelease: true,
    hermesFlagsRelease: ["-O", "-output-source-map"],
    hermesFlagsDebug: ["-O", "-output-source-map"],
    // entryFile: "index.js",
    // bundleInPre: true
]
```

but still no works.

Comment: Did you check the build output logs for any error messages or warnings related to sourcemap generation? These logs might provide insights into what could be causing the issue.

Comment: there is only warning regarding gradle and typescript issues. other than that nothing.